# angular checkbox $watch not working

Tags: angularjs

I need live update my model when I selecting the checkboxes. But when  I run this code : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

After I remove the map function & added console.log(nv).

Then initially it print a empty array. Then while I selecting a checkbox it returns the object correctly. Here is my code. Looking for your help..

//my Controller

```
$scope.selection = [];    

$scope.$watch('items|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv) {

     $scope.selection = nv.map(function (item) {
      return item.id;
 });
```

}, true);

//view

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:global.query | orderBy: name">

    <input class="tile-check" id="check-0" type="checkbox" name="delete"
                      ng-model="item.selected">

</div>
```

source : http://jsbin.com/ImAqUC/1

Comment: i see its working.. whats the problem?

Comment: @HarishR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was the $watch is called before set the item variable. So I put a if around that.

```
if(nv){

     $scope.selection = nv.map(function (item) {
        return item.id;
     });
}
```